# How to download attachments from incoming emails assigned to a particular category and change the category after the download?

Tags: vba, outlook

I created a macro to download attachments from emails assigned to a particular category and assign the email to a different category.

I categorize emails with a specific subject line using rules and have attached the macro to the rule to download the attachments assigned to this category. The macro afterwards re-assigns these emails to a different category.

```
Public Sub SaveNewInvoices(oItem As Outlook.Item)

Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
Dim cats() As String
Dim i As Integer

sSaveFolder = "D:\Users\fakathuria\Desktop\Invoices_Prepared\"

cats = Split(oItem.Categories, ";")

    For i = 0 To UBound(cats)

        If LCase$(cats(i)) = LCase$(Invoice_To_Be_Downloaded) Then

            For Each oAttachment In oItem.Attachments
                oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
                oItem.Categories = "Invoice_Downloaded"
            Next

        EndIf

    Next

End Sub
```

I expect attachments to be downloaded in the specified folder. However, attachments are not saved in the designated folder and the category does not change.

Comment: I added `EndIf` after `Next` which You were missing during edition of your post. It would cause error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`Outlook.Item` ...  Never heard of it. Everything looks like you should be using `Outlook.MailItem`.

Easy to understand the confusion if you were using `Outlook.Items` in a different sub and then call this while passing `Outlook.Items(index)`